# Interface Builder: Is there a way to show the on-screen keyboard?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, keyboard

I want to check that my iPhone interfaces designed in Interface Builder look ok when the on-screen keyboard is shown.  I know how to set the 'simulated user interface elements' such as the top and bottom tab bars on or off.

Is there anything similar for the on-screen keyboard?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could start with a Horizontal Guide (Editor > Add Horizontal Guide) 216 px from the botton. That's exactly how high the keyboard is.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know you could do that.  Thanks. Incidentally, in landscape mode the keyboard is 162 pixels high.

Comment: Just note that the keyboard is subject to change, considering Retina display and similar display size/resolution changes.

Comment: where the hell is this option

Comment: it's under Editor now, I edited the answer. (btw you can always click help in the menu and enter the name of a menu item)

Comment: @fabian789 it's now under Editor > Guides > Add Horizontal Guide. Also, you need to have a view, rather than a view controller, currently selected.

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain but I believe the answer is no. You cab however, "Simulate Interface" and run the XIB file in the simulator, which should accomplish what you want.